# How to make github actions step fail if the previous step has failed?

Tags: makefile, github-actions

I have written a ci process to build and deploy docker images using github actions. There is a strange behavior seen i.e. when the make file fails due to any reason the steps in the github actions are still continued instead of stopping at the failed step. I am using only one job in my ci and multiple steps within it.

Example error: make[1]: [../../Makefile:22: docker-build-generic] Error 1 (ignored)

Answer (score 0):

Github Actions do not actually run sequentially: they will run in parallel if there are enough resources. If one job relies on another, use the [needs syntax](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idneeds).

Modified example from the documentation:

```yaml
jobs:
  job1:
  job2:
    needs: job1
```

Here job2 will wait for job1 to succeed before running. If job1 fails, job2 will not run.

Comment: Thanks! Is this same applied to steps? I thought steps run sequentially. I am only using one job with many steps in it.

Comment: Steps should be running in order, [see here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/understanding-github-actions#jobs). If a step returns a non-zero exit code but GitHub is continuing on to the next step, and you're not setting [continue-on-error](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepscontinue-on-error), perhaps you've found a bug?

Comment: Another thought, perhaps you could add `echo $?` to the next step to see what the exit code of the previous, 'failing' step actually was?